# I cannot find the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react and I need some help when I´m trying to bring some "products" from an array of objects that I have in one file of my react app called "products.js".

The thing is that **I am able** to draw the products within the array in the Home Screen. However when I try to draw those products on my details products page (this one is a page where I can see an individual product details) "ProductDetails.js" I'm getting the error (regardless if I try to bring product.name or product.price or whatever):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

In order for you to have an idea about what I'm talking about I will share to you some snippets from my code to put you in context. I will Start with the exact error message and I will finish with a Glance of My Project Dependencies.

***Error Message***

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
ProductDetails
C:/Users/jjimennz/OneDrive/Desktop/eCommerce MERN Stack/Sprint1/frontend/src/views/ProductDetails.js:19

 16 | const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  17 |   const product = products.find((p) => p._id === match.params.id);
  18 | 
> 19 |   return <div>{product.name}</div>;
  20 | };
  21 | 
  22 | export default ProductDetails;
```

***this is the View I'm having TROUBLE with and is not only with the "product.name" I happens with anything "product.price" "product.image"...  this is the details product screen, the view that is supposed to show me each individual product with its details on its own page, which I called  "ProductDetails.js"***

```
import React from "react";
import products from "../products";

const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === match.params.id);

  return <div>{product.name}</div>;
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

***This is the File  with the array containing the products I want to draw on the above product details screen. this file is the one called  "products.js":***

```
const products = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Nemeziz 19.4",
    image:
      "https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/75987ad2e31644d59d24ab3000fce766_9366/Botines_Nemeziz_19.4_Pasto_Sintetico_Verde_FV3317_41_detail.jpg",
    description: "Breve descripcion de los zapatos",
    brand: "Adidas",
    category: "Zapatos",
    price: 89.99,
    countInStock: 20,
    rating: 4.5,
    numReviews: 14,
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "Adidas Ace",
    image: "https://www.sports-ws.com/img/item/F163AD0/F163AD0654.jpg",
    description: "Breve descripcion de los zapatos",
    brand: "Adidas",
    category: "Zapatos",
    price: 149.99,
    countInStock: 8,
    rating: 4.5,
    numReviews: 15,
  },
];

export default products
```

***This is the view for the Home Screen, where I show all of the products within the above array, this one works just fine and draws every product within the array on the screen. this one is called "HomeScreen.js"***

```
import React from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import products from "../products";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

**This is the Product component, this one basically draws each individual product within the array on the above Home Screen view. This one as the above Home Screen also works just fine, it brings me the product with its name, its price and image. I did call this component "Product.js"***

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "./Rating";

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
      <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={product.image} variant="top" />
      </Link>
      <Card.Body>
        <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
          <Card.Title as="div">
            <strong>{product.name}</strong>
          </Card.Title>
        </Link>

        <Card.Text as="div">
          <Rating
            value={product.rating}
            text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
          />
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Text as="h3">${product.price}</Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

***"App.js" file, so you have a better understanding about what is going on on my project***

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./views/HomeScreen";
import ProductDetails from "./views/ProductDetails";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
          <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductDetails} />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***This is My "package.json" file with dependencies in my project, just in case It helps to help me with this***

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

***Here you have an Screenshot of the error message on the products details view***
[image: error]

***Here you have an Screenshot of the page that works the Home Screen***
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that your `.find()` method is returning `undefined`, so you can't access properties on `product` such as `.name` as it is `undefined`. The `.find()` method will return `undefined` when the callback function doesn't return a truthy value for any of your items within your array.

In this case, your callback will only return `true` when your product id matches the id exactly (in both value and type) of the id used in your URL:

```js
p._id === match.params.id
```

However, the above will never be `true`, as `p._id` in your data is a **number** type, and `match.params.id` is a **string** type, so the two are never considered equal under strict equality `===`. As a result, `.find()` never finds a match and you get `undefind`. Instead, you can use "loose" equality comparison `==`, which doesn't need the types to match:

```js
const product = products.find((p) => p._id == match.params.id);
```

Alternatively, you can convert the type manually using a method such as `Number()` and stick with `===`:

```js
const product = products.find((p) => p._id === Number(match.params.id));
```

---

#### Other things to try

I've noticed that this question has gathered quite a lot of attention, so I thought I'd add another common reason why you might see this error (note these reasons don't apply to OPs code).

Firstly, the error means that whatever you're using `.name` on has a value of `undefined`. Typically this can happen if you're making an API call with something like `fetch()` or doing some other asynchronous task within a `useEffect()` which sets the value of whatever you're using `.name` on. There are two ways to combat this issue, one way is to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to prevent access of the `.name` property if the object is `null` or `undefined`, eg:

```js
<strong>{product?.name}</strong>
```

Or, another way is to assign your state value so that it initially isn't undefined, eg:

```js
const [product, setProduct] = useState({}); // <-- using `product.name` now works, whereas doing `useState()` wouldn't work
```

Comment: This Information Helped me a Lot!!  Thanks you very much

Comment: @JabidJimenez no worries!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this: Make changes in below two files only.

For ProductDetails.js

import React from "react";
import products from "../products";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProductDetails = () => {
    const {id} = useParams()
    const product = products.find(p=>p._id === id)
    return <div>{product.name}</div>;
  
}

export default ProductDetails;
```

for App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./views/HomeScreen";
import ProductDetails from "./views/ProductDetails";
function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Header/>
          <main className='py-3'>
            <Container>
              <Routes> 
                <Route path ='/' element={<HomeScreen/>} exact />
                <Route path ='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetails/>}/>
              </Routes>
            </Container>
          </main>
          <Footer/>
        </Router>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`match.params.id` type of string, so you shoud be to parse string because `_id` as int, yo can use `parseInt(1)`

```
    import React from "react";
    import products from "../products";

    const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
       const product = products.find((p) => p._id === parseInt(match.params.id));

       return <div>{product.name}</div>;
    };

    export default ProductDetails;
```

you can see full documentation https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    import React from 'react'
    import products from '../products'
    import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

    function ProductDetails() {
        const { id } = useParams();
        const product = products.find((p) => Number(p._id) === Number(id));
        return (
            <div>
                {product.image}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default ProductDetails
```

Comment: This answer could really use some description/explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a react native Expo project, and when I ran command 'npx expo start', it showed an error. I fixed it by running this command:

```
npx expo start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in JS for this code and then retry this code below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import products from '../products';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProductDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const product = products?.find((p) => Number(p._id) === Number(id));
  return (
    <div>
      {product.image}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetails
```